# asp.net mvc dropdownlist with directory files list

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to show all files from a folder "newsletter" with category list. but when I use following code, I got error, my code is :

```
public ActionResult templatelist()
        {
            var data = _session.emailForcampaigns.Select(m => m.category).Distinct().AsQueryable(); 
            ViewBag.ddlCategory = new SelectList(data, "category", "category");
            return View(Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/newsletter")));
        }
```

and i have following lines in view

```
<table class="tables" >
    <tr>
        <td>Fiels</td>
        <td>
            <select id="template" name="template">
            @foreach (var fullPath in Model)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fullPath);
                <option value="@fileName"> @fileName</option>
            }
            </select>
        </td>
     </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Category </td>
        <td>
             @Html.DropDownList("ddlCategory", null, new { @class = "dropdown " })
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

but i am getting error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to specify a data source for the drop-down list:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("ddlCategory", new SelectList(ViewBag.ddlCategory , "category", "category"))
```